# HttpRequest + proxy working not correct

Tags: c#, post, proxy, httprequest

Could you help me please with this issue, I have correct working authentication for my site, but now I need add proxy to my request. Some times it's work, some times crashesю I try do it

```
var request = new HttpRequest();
request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse("36.250.74.88:80");
request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
string post = request.Post("http://www.webpage/login/", "action=login&email=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(login) + "&password=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pass, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)) + "&remember=on", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").ToString();
```

But I got an exception for my **request.post** - "HttpExceprion was unhandled. Failed to load the body of the response message from HTTP-server".

I delete try\catch block for catching the exception reason.

P.S. current proxy server is worked, I got the message on server(website) about login from another IP...

Comment: Any ideas? :) Help plz